# Get values for a subset of keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm caching some data in a `Map` by Id. And in an additional array a store the Ids of all changed objects.

Is there a way to get all changed values from my chache?

```
var cache = {id1 : {a:1, b:2},
             id2 : {a:5, b:2},
             id3 : {a:1, b:4}};

var changed = ["id1", "id3"];
```

Right now I solve it like this, but I bet there is a smarter solution in JS.

```
var result = [];
for(var id of changed) {
    result.push(cache[id]);
}
```

Comment: *but I bet there is a smarter solution in JS* Your solution is fine as is.

Comment: you can also do `var result = changed.map(id=>cache[id]);` but that's without any kind of importance

Comment: @gurvinder372 sure, but I prefer smart single line statements :) thanks Denys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array.map`

```js
var cache = {id1 : {a:1, b:2},
             id2 : {a:5, b:2},
             id3 : {a:1, b:4}};

var changed = ["id1", "id3"];

var result = changed.map(id => cache[id]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Basti Saw this answer after posting mine, haha! Let me know if you need that, else I'll remove mine :)

Comment: @DenysSéguret harman's answer was different (and not relevant, for what it's worth).

Comment: @DenysSéguret it felt like the answer came at the same second as your comment :(